# Variable disappearing inside loop? Powershell

Tags: powershell

The following code works.  Imagine the variable $Datfilecontents is being read from a file in my main script before being passed on. The script should try each part of the array in a UNC like so

\\1404397769\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE
\\SAO-LDMS\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE

in the script below the for each loop sees both the 1404397769 and the SAO-LDMS and tries both.

In the main script where $DatFileContents is being read from a .dat file ( the value is the same the echos before hand are OK ) The problem is that when in the loop this is what happens..

\\1404397769\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE
gets passed first as it should....
then
\\SAO-LDMS

why is the last part of the $NetworkPath getting lost in the loop?

the only difference in the main script i am working on is the $Datfilecontents was read from a file so as long as the data is the same it should work? i dont see how the variable that is not even in the array is getting lost?

Am i missing something here? Any help appreciated.

```
$Datfilecontents = "1404397769;SAO-LDMS"
echo $1 "Before the split"
$1 = $DatFileContents.split(";");
echo $1 "after the split"
[array]::Reverse($1)
echo $1 "after the reverse"
Do
{
Foreach ($i in $1)
{
    [String]$i


    $net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
    [String]$NetworkPath = "\\$i\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE"


    $NetworkPath
    Write-Host $NetworkPath "THIS IS THE PATH"

    Try
    {
        $net.MapNetworkDrive("M:", $NetworkPath, $false, "domain\user", "password")
    echo "Mapping Drive M to Preferred Server"}
    Catch
    {echo "Failed to Map Drive M to Preferred Server" 





}

}
until (Test-Path "M:\LDMS BUILD")


This is the output from the main script.

\\\1404398737\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE THIS IS THE PATH
Failed to Map Drive M to Preferred Server
\\\SAO-LDMS THIS IS THE PATH
Failed to Map Drive M to Preferred Server
```

As you can see the second pass is not showing the share? so if cannot map the drive. However the share variable must be valid as it puts it after the first pass?

```
The full output from the code above.
Before the split
1404397769
SAO-LDMS
after the split
SAO-LDMS
1404397769
after the reverse
SAO-LDMS
\\SAO-LDMS\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE
\\SAO-LDMS\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE THIS IS THE PATH
Mapping Drive M to Preferred Server
1404397769
\\1404397769\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE
\\1404397769\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE THIS IS THE PATH
Failed to Map Drive M to Preferred Server
```

The full output from the main script. you can see the values are present before it attempts to pass them. But it removes the share from the first pass?

```
Before the split
1404401722
SAO-LDMS
after the split 
SAO-LDMS
1404401722
after the reverse
SAO-LDMS
\\SAO-LDMS
\\SAO-LDMS THIS IS THE PATH
Failed to Map Drive M to Preferred Server
1404401722
\\1404401722\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE
\\1404401722\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE THIS IS THE PATH
Failed to Map Drive M to Preferred Server
```

OK This is the main script - i really cannot see a difference.

```
$DatFileLoc = "c:\Program Files (x86)\LANDesk\LDClient\sdmcache\$DatFile";
    Write-Host $DatFileLoc
    $DatFileLoc
    Write-Host "Preferred Server File found at $DatFileLoc";
    Write-Host "Getting File Contents";
    $DatFileContents = Get-Content $DatFileLoc
    Write-Host $DatFileContents

$DatFileContents = $DatFileContents -replace "\?", ";";
Write-Host $DatFileContents
echo $1 "Before the split"
$1 = $DatFileContents.split(";");
echo $1 "after the split"       

  [array]::Reverse($1)
echo $1 "after the reverse"

Do
{
Foreach ($i in $1)
{
    [String]$i

    $net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
    [String]$NetworkPath = "\\$i\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE"


    $NetworkPath
    Write-Host $NetworkPath "THIS IS THE PATH"

    Try
    {
        $net.MapNetworkDrive("M:", $NetworkPath, $false, "domain\user", "password")
    echo "Mapping Drive M to Preferred Server"}
    Catch
    {echo "Failed to Map Drive M to Preferred Server" }

}

}
until (Test-Path "M:\LDMS BUILD")
```

And the output from that...

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\LANDesk\LDClient\sdmcache\preferredservers.dat
Preferred Server File found at c:\Program Files    (x86)\LANDesk\LDClient\sdmcache\preferredservers.dat
Getting File Contents
1404403455?SAO-LDMS
1404403455;SAO-LDMS
Before the split
1404403455
SAO-LDMS
after the split
SAO-LDMS
1404403455
after the reverse
SAO-LDMS
\\SAO-LDMS
\\SAO-LDMS THIS IS THE PATH
Failed to Map Drive M to Preferred Server
1404403455
\\1404403455\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE
\\1404403455\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE THIS IS THE PATH
Failed to Map Drive M to Preferred Server
```

Comment: I copied the script you have, commented out the Try/Catch and Do/Until loop lines, and the script works fine for me. You must be leaving something out.

Comment: The code i posted does work fine. the same code in the main script does not - however there is one difference - the $Datfilecontents is not being explicitly assigned - its coming from a text file. however it should not ignore the share - thats not even part of the array? its really confusing me

Comment: showing output from both scripts - you can see the share is removed on first pass of loop - i have no idea why?

Comment: I changed mine to `$Datfilecontents = GC test.txt` and get the same results as before, so it's not reading it from a file that's the issue. Something else is different between this and your main script.

Comment: i will look through again thanks - but what would make the loop ignore the last part only once through? i assure you im looking for difference! i just cannot see it.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician i have posted the code that fails am i missing something?

Comment: Do you know what the encoding is on the file? Perhaps reading it as ASCII (the default) is causing issues with a hidden character or something. I wish I knew of a way to sanitize strings in PS, but I don't. Maybe one of the all stars will chime in with something clever towards that end. (If you don't know the encoding [check here](http://poshcode.org/2059) for help finding it). Oh, also, if you don't reverse the order does it have issues with the first loop, or with the same SAO-LDMS entry?

Comment: Hi same if i dont reverse. I have tried using the array integers too and passing them into a String and no matter what i do if the info is from the file it behaves like this! i will check the file its actually a .dat file - maybe thats doing it...

Comment: Its a ASCII file ? this is baffling me... I have tried trimming the strings.. but the bit its missing out once in the loop is not even from the file!?

Comment: This really speaks to the issue being within the file, and not the code. Without having the file itself there's not much further I can do to help at this time.

Comment: this is driving me nuts.. i have now created a brand new text file. written the contents of the dat file to this file and reading the new file... same problem. If i declare the value ( which i cannot do as its an unknown ) it works.. something is doing it. ha

Comment: I can not replicate the problem with the code provided and a .txt file containing _1404403455?SAO-LDMS_

Comment: can you upload files to this site or share links to files?

Comment: You can not upload files, but you can post a link.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/?2ruraap6ghb7m17    my code

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/?584pio29ofaw51l   my text file

Comment: that code pointing to that file ( which is a new one created from the dat file ) will give same problem. if you use the explicit decalration it works. see if you get the same weirdness - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved your file, changed the path to my download folder (user name changed for my safety). This is the code I ran from my ISE and console:

```
$DatFileContents = Get-Content "C:\Users\TMTech\Downloads\preferredservers.txt";
$DatFileContents = $DatFileContents -replace "\?", ";";
echo $DatFileContents "Before the split"
$1 = $DatFileContents.split(";");
echo $1 "after the split"
[array]::Reverse($1)
echo $1 "after the reverse"
Do
{
    Foreach ($i in $1)
    {
        [String]$i

        $net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
        [String]$NetworkPath = "\\$i\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE"


        $NetworkPath
        Write-Host $NetworkPath "THIS IS THE PATH"

        Try
        {
            $net.MapNetworkDrive("M:", $NetworkPath, $false, "domain\user", "password")
        echo "Mapping Drive M to Preferred Server"}
        Catch
        { echo "Failed to Map Drive M to Preferred Server" }




    }

}
until (Test-Path "M:\LDMS BUILD")
```

This is what happened when I ran that:

```
1404418053;SAO-LDMS
Before the split
1404418053
SAO-LDMS
after the split
SAO-LDMS
1404418053
after the reverse
SAO-LDMS
\\SAO-LDMS \LDMS_MASTER_SHARE
\\SAO-LDMS \LDMS_MASTER_SHARE THIS IS THE PATH
Failed to Map Drive M to Preferred Server
1404418053
\\1404418053\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE
\\1404418053\LDMS_MASTER_SHARE THIS IS THE PATH
Failed to Map Drive M to Preferred Server
SAO-LDMS
\\SAO-LDMS \LDMS_MASTER_SHARE
\\SAO-LDMS \LDMS_MASTER_SHARE THIS IS THE PATH
```

A few notes:

- $1 doesn't exist when you try to echo it in `echo $1 "Before the split"` you probably mean to echo $datfilecontents.
- The semicolon at the ends of lines aren't needed in PowerShell.
- You don't need to declare `[String]$i` or `[String]$NetworkPath` since they're going to be strings anyway.
- You can do away with every `echo` in there, those lines would be sent to the output by default.
- None of these things would stop the script from working though.

It's a shame you don't have 20 reputation, we could just take this conversation into Stack Overflow's chat server in a private room rather than responding to comments back and forth.

Comment: yeah its a bit messy with some of the things i tried - i will see if that exact code works here... thanks

Comment: The results are in that code block. Everything ran fine for me.

Comment: which part is reading the text file? can you post working code - with read the file - then i can paste it and rule out my machine.. send me the exact code that works i have a feeling its machine related if that fails here.

Comment: Thanks @TheMadTechnician it was my machine.. i had to strip out the space after SAO-LDMS but on another machine it worked... guess i need to rebuild my machine thanks anyway